# MySQL if statement

Tags: mysql

I want to update all rows when `invoiceID` is `NULL` else update only the rows where all `invoiceID`'s are the same.

My current SQL statement is as follows:

```
UPDATE Table SET strPOnummer = '123' 
WHERE strPOnummer = '456' AND strPOnummer != '' AND strPOnummer IS NOT NULL
```

So, when `Table.invoiceID` is `NULL`, it should update all rows, else update only the rows where `invoiceID` is the same.

Comment: what is strPOnummer vs invoiceID ? is the same ?

Comment: @ajreal No, it's not the same. It should update `strPOnummer` on every row, except when `invoiceID` is not null (but then on where the `invoiceID` is the same).

Comment: pardon my ignorance, I just don't understand what do you mean by invoiceID is the same (with what?)

Comment: This question needs to be rewritten. Describe your table(s), and perhaps add some examples to illustrate what you want the query to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that invoiceID is an input parameter, you could do this:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET strPOnummer = '123' 
WHERE --your non-invoiceID filtering conditions go here 
  AND (Table.invoiceID = @InvoiceID OR @InvoiceID IS NULL)
```

In this case if the @InvoiceID parameter is not null then the first condition will have to be met as the second will never be met, but if it is null then each row of the table will be matched by the second part of the condition and thus the first one isn't relevant anymore

Answer (score 0):

I will write just example not code to use, please modify it yourself as needed

```
SELECT IF(invoiceID=1,
   (UPDATE table as tmp SET... WHERE tmp.id=table.id), 
   (UPDATE table as tmp SET... WHERE tmp.id=table.id)
) FROM table);
```